# mw wp form datepicker のjs引数の書き方を教えてください

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui

wordpressのプラグイン「mw wp form」の日付（datepicker）で、期間を指定したいのですが、うまく反映されません。

例えば、本日〜2017年7月20日までしか選択出来ないようにする場合、
`[mwform_datepicker name="" size="" js='"minDate": "0","maxDate": "new Date( 2017, 7, 20 )"']`
のように、jsの引数の部分を
`"minDate": "0","maxDate": "new Date( 2017, 7, 20 )"`
と記述しました。

minDateの方はちゃんと本日以前は選択出来ないようになったのですが、maxDateは指定出来ていないようで、7月20日以降も選択できてしまいます。

どなたかご教授お願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript では、

```js
"new Date( 2017, 7, 20 )"
```

のようにダブルクォーテーションで囲うと、文字列になります。
Date オブジェクトを生成する場合は、クォートせずに [Date コンストラクタ](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)を呼び出します。

```js
new Date( 2017, 7, 20 )
```